# Shared element transition is not working, if app open through deep link

Tags: android, shared-element-transition, launchmode

Im added shared element transition to launch Activity B from activity A.
Normally shared element transition is working, but its not working, if app launch through deep link and showing Activity A view.

Activity B launch mode : SingleTask

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution**
One way to solve this is launch No UI Activity(RouterActivity) from deeplink and form this activity you can try launch with animation.
Inside Router Activity set theme in onCreate.

```
 getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.NO_UI, true);
```

In style

```
  <style name="Theme.NO_UI" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

And launch screen with animation from onCreate().

**Second Solution**
Define animation in style:
Define a new animation style in your styles.xml, as follows

```
    <style name="MyTheme.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
      <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/your_desired_animation</item>
```

Then set this style in a theme (themes.xml) as follows :

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
      <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyTheme.Window</item>
</style>
```

And then you can simply set these themes to every activity in your AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
<activity 
  android:name="your_activity" 
  android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
</activity>
```